# Какая кодировка используется в Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, кодировка, unicode

Начал изучать кодировки, и возникло очень много вопросов. Какая кодировка в Windows 10? Какие процессы выполняются в этой кодировке, а какие нет? Я знаю что Python, например, использует кодировку UTF-32, и если эта кодировка отличается от кодировки в Windows 10, то как это вообще может правильно работать? Почему кодировка может быть другая и в Интернете? У кого может быть своя кодировка, а у кого нет, и каким образом все они кооперируются, если работают в разных кодировках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никакие процессы ни в какой кодировке не выполняются. Кодировка применяется только при выводе текста на экран. Во все остальное время это такие же данные, как и числа, например.

Аналогия: Последовательность букв "pain" в кодировке "английский язык" означает "боль", а кодировке "французский язык" - "хлеб". Однако для пересылки этой последовательности или её сохранения это не имеет значения. Это важно только в момент чтения.

Так и с кодировкой символов. Кодировка при меняется только в момент вывода текста на экран или бумагу, от неё зависит как будет выглядеть та или иная последовательность чисел.

Comment: Понял, а какая кодировка в Windows 10 всё-таки?

Comment: Странно, пишите, что поняли, но при этом продолжаете задавать этот же вопрос

Comment: @holyDemon12 в такой формулировке вопрос не имеет смысла

Comment: @holyDemon12 что вы вообще понимаете под словами "кодировка в Windows"?

Comment: @Эникейщик под кодировкой в Windows 10 понимаю кодировку, которая используется при выводе текста на экран в Windows

Comment: @holyDemon12 на экран выводится не текст, а пиксели

Comment: @holyDemon12, не знаю, как в десятке, а раньше (скажем, в седьмой) в  эмуляторах консоли был целый зоопарк. Причем, в некоторых вывод нормально отображался в одной кодировке (например, в cp866 (это еще из ДОС-а, с псевдографикой)), ввод через stdin тоже был в ней, а вот аргументы командной строки передавались в программу в cp1251 (т.е. в той, в какой обычно набивается текст в редакторе). И т.д. и т.п. Я на это дело посмотрел, плюнул и больше к винде не прикасался